# how to link dramsim2 library interface with a PINtool

Tags: c++, config, linker-errors

I want to use DRAMSim2 as library interface in a developing PINtool.

I try to be familiar with dramsim_test.cpp that includes dramsim_test.h, that includes DRAMSim.h (in a specific directory).

If i put these files in the directory of my PINtool an include them (except .cpp. for this i use the code in the PINtool) i get a linker (i suppose) error:

```
undefined symbol: _ZN7DRAMSim23getMemorySystemInstanceERKSsS1_S1_S1_jPSs
```

The PINtool has a config file that writes these:

```
## Libraries to link
ifeq ($(TARGET_OS),mac)
    APP_LIBS := -lm
else
    APP_LIBS := -Wl,--as-needed -lm
endif
DL_LIB :=
APP_LIB_ATOMIC := -latomic
APP_LIB_XED := -lxed
TOOL_LIBS := -lpin -lxed
SATOOL_LIBS := -lsapin -lxed
CXX_LIBS :=
```

The makefile of dramsim example has this:

```
$(CXX) -g -o dramsim_test dramsim_test.cpp -I../ -L../ -ldramsim -Wl,-rpath=../
```

I suppose that i have to add somewhere in the pintool config file the -ldramism option but i dont know how.

Im not familiar also with linker options, configuration files etc. How can i link them?

**UPDATE:** The problem solved. After changing the conf file by adding -ldramsim and didnt work, i tried to move the libdramsim.so into the folder of allcache_v7.cpp and is ok...

Answer (score 2):

Just add `-ldramsim` to the `TOOL_LIBS` variable. You will also need to add its path. So change the line:

```
TOOL_LIBS := -lpin -lxed
```

to

```
TOOL_LIBS := -lpin -lxed -L/path/to/dramsim/ -ldramsim
```

**UPDATE:** Now that you have successfully built your library, you're almost there. You just need to make sure it is found by the dynamic linker at load time. In theory, this is done as follows from your shell prompt:

```
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/dramsim:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
> #command to invoke binary that uses your library allcache_v7.so
```

If this still gives you problems, check if the linker can resolve it:

```
> ldd allcache_v7.so | grep dramsim
```

This should tell you whether the linker can resolve libdramsin.so or not. Try it before and after the `export ...` command - see if the output changes from something like "Not found" to the true path of the library.

Comment: thank you for your answer... but the problem still exists. I changed the line you said and didnt work. I also tried to change this: CXX_LPATHS := -I ../../../DRAMSim2/ -L ../../../DRAMSim2/ (the paths are correct but i dont know how to use -I and -L)

Comment: Can you get your PINTool build to be verbose, so it outputs the compiler command line(s) it uses, and share this?

Comment: `g++ -DBIGARRAY_MULTIPLIER=1 -Wall -Werror -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fno-stack-protector -DTARGET_IA32E -DHOST_IA32E -fPIC -DTARGET_LINUX -I../../../source/include/pin -I../../../source/include/pin/gen -I../../../extras/components/include -I../../../extras/xed-intel64/include -I../../../source/tools/InstLib -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -c -o obj-intel64/allcache_v7.o allcache_v7.cpp`

Comment: and also:
`g++ -shared -Wl,--hash-style=sysv -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--version-script=../../../source/include/pin/pintool.ver -o obj-intel64/allcache_v7.so obj-intel64/allcache_v7.o -L../../../intel64/lib -L../../../intel64/lib-ext -L../../../intel64/runtime/glibc -L../../../extras/xed-intel64/lib -lpin -lxed -lpindwarf -ldl`

Comment: OK. I think try this: instead of adding `-ldramsim` to `CXX_LIBS`, add it to `TOOL_LIBS` instead. So the relevant line becomes `TOOL_LIBS := -lpin -lxed -ldramsim`

Comment: Can you dump your gcc lines again? Have they changed?

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldramsim

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Aha! That's progress! Now all you need to do is add the search path for that library. Assuming you know where the `libdramsim.so` is located, and this is at say `/path/to/dramsim/libdramsim.so`, just modify your `TOOL_LIBS` variable further like this: `TOOL_LIBS := -lpin -lxed -L/path/to/dramsim/ -ldramsim`

Comment: the error still exists... (library directory is 100% correct)

`E: Unable to load /home/taleporos/Dropbox/PIN/source/tools/MemTrace/obj-intel64/allcache_v7.so: libdramsim.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Can you please repost the current gcc compile (note: not error) lines?

Comment: Hang on sorry... The above error that you posted - does this mean you're no longer getting the `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find ...` error?

Comment: `g++ -DBIGARRAY_MULTIPLIER=1 -Wall -Werror -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fno-stack-protector -DTARGET_IA32E -DHOST_IA32E -fPIC -DTARGET_LINUX -I../../../source/include/pin -I../../../source/include/pin/gen -I../../../extras/components/include -I../../../extras/xed-intel64/include -I../../../source/tools/InstLib -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -c -o obj-intel64/allcache_v7.o allcache_v7.cpp`

Comment: `g++ -shared -Wl,--hash-style=sysv -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--version-script=../../../source/include/pin/pintool.ver -o obj-intel64/allcache_v7.so obj-intel64/allcache_v7.o -L../../../intel64/lib -L../../../intel64/lib-ext -L../../../intel64/runtime/glibc -L../../../extras/xed-intel64/lib -lpin -lxed -I../../../DRAMSim2 -L../../../DRAMSim2 -ldramsim -lpindwarf -ldl`

Comment: Thanks, please also answer my later comment

Comment: Your observation is correct!
before:`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldramsim`
now:`E: Unable to load /home/taleporos/Dropbox/PIN/source/tools/MemTrace/obj-intel64/allcache_v7.so: libdramsim.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: If the answer is yes, which I suspect it is, I think you've now successfully built your library, and your latest problem is now actually loading it. I suggest try this: before running whatever commands you run, in the shell where you're running them type `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/dramsim` using the full path to `libdramsim.so`'s directory

Comment: i did the export but nothing happened again... :-(

Comment: Can you please try all of the steps in my update to the answer above and see where you get?

Comment: after ldd allcache_v7.so | grep dramsim

`libdramsim.so => /home/taleporos/Dropbox/PIN/DRAMSim2/libdramsim.so (0x00007f9df1bda000)`

but the problem still cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory

Comment: Can you please share the command line that is actually invoking the application that uses your built library `allcache_v7.so`?