# Error Building Pin Tool that Uses External Library

Tags: compilation, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, intel-pin

I declared a function foo() in a header file imp.h and implemented it in imp.c. Then I generated a shared library named libimp.so and in my Pin tool I called foo().

In order to link the tool with this new library I added the following definitions to makefile.rules in its directory:

```
TOOL_CXXFLAGS += -I/path/to/imp.h
TOOL_LPATHS += -L/path/to/libimp.so
TOOL_LIBS += -limp
```

I also set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the /path/to/libimp.so. But, at runtime, if I use foo(), the following error will be received:

```
dlopen failed. library "libimp.so" not found.
```

The library is OK when I call it from a simple test program. Any ideas?

Comment: https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/pinheads/conversations/topics/12356

Answer (score 0):

> I also set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the /path/to/libimp.so

If the full path to `libimp.so` is *literally* `/path/to/libimp.so`, then the correct value for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is `/path/to`, and *not* `/path/to/libimp.so`.

(It isn't clear from your question whether you understand this.)

You may wish to link your pintool with `-Wl,--rpath=/path/to` so you don't have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at all.

Comment: The path is OK. I also used -Wl,--rpath=/path/to, but the error exists. There is a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707344/how-to-link-dramsim2-library-interface-with-a-pintool.